# Extract pages and structured content from pdf and save it to data-frame

Tags: r, parsing, stringr, read-text

I have a PDF with several 100 pages. The pdf contains press releases that have a different length (from 1 page to several pages).

Each press release, however, starts and ends with a similar structure:

Example of the head of one press release: `OTS0071 5 AI 0339 MAA0001          Do, 14.Dez 2017`

Example of the tail of the respective press release: `141028 Dez 17`

Reading the pdf file into R is easy:

`df <- readtext("ots.pdf", encoding = "UTF8")`

Here is an example file:

```
structure(list(doc_id = "ots.pdf", text = "OTS0071 5 AI 0339 MAA0001                            Do, 14.Dez 2017\n\nText of press release 1\n\n\n\nOTS0071                   2017-12-14/10:28\n\n141028 Dez 17\n\n\n\n\nOTS0184 5 AI 0120 MAA0001                           Di, 12.Dez 2017\n\nText of press release 2\n\n\n\nOTS0184 2017-12-12/15:46\n\n121546 Dez 17\n\n\n\n\nOTS0018 5 AI 0206 MAA0002                    So, 10.Dez 2017\n\nText of press release 3\n\n\nOTS0018 2017-12-10/12:00\n\n101200 Dez 17\n"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("readtext", "data.frame"))
```

But how can I tell R to read in every single press release as a new observation with the following three variables: ID, date, text

`id` = the OTS number of the press release, in the example above it is *OTS0071*

`date`= the date of the press release, in the example above it is *Do, 14.Dez 2017* (i.e., Thursday 14 December 2017)

`text` = the rest of the text between the head and the tail

I managed to extract all press releases and save them into a list with the following command:

```
x <- str_extract_all(df$text, "(OTS[0-9]{4})((.|\n)*?)([[:digit:]]{6} [[:alpha:]]{3} [[:digit:]]{2})")
```

But how can I transform x (a list) into a data frame and add the variables `id`, `date`, and `text`?

Answer (score 1):

I think I finally solved it myself.

**Required Packages**:

```
require(pacman)

p_load(readtext,    # read files
       lubridate,   # work with date-times and time-spans
       plyr,        # Splitting, Applying and Combining Data
       tidyverse    # data manipulation and plotting
)
```

**First**, reading in the pdf:

```
df <- readtext("ots.pdf", encoding = "UTF8")
```

or use **example data set**:

```
df <- structure(list(doc_id = "ots.pdf", text = "OTS0071 5 AI 0339 MAA0001                            Do, 14.Dez 2017\n\nText of press release 1\n\n\n\nOTS0071                   2017-12-14/10:28\n\n141028 Dez 17\n\n\n\n\nOTS0184 5 AI 0120 MAA0001                           Di, 12.Dez 2017\n\nText of press release 2\n\n\n\nOTS0184 2017-12-12/15:46\n\n121546 Dez 17\n\n\n\n\nOTS0018 5 AI 0206 MAA0002                    So, 10.Dez 2017\n\nText of press release 3\n\n\nOTS0018 2017-12-10/12:00\n\n101200 Dez 17\n"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("readtext", "data.frame"))
```

**Second**, extracting the different press releases in the text:

```
x <- str_extract_all(df$text, "(OTS[0-9]{4})((.|\n)*?)([[:digit:]]{4} [[:alpha:]]{3} [[:digit:]]{2})")
```

**Third**, transforming the resulting list to a tibble data frame and give the column a name (i.e., "pressReleases"):

```
df_tibble <- as_tibble(x, "ots")
colnames(df_tibble) <- "pressReleases"
```

**Fourth, create the variables and remove variable "pressReleases":

```
df_tibble <- df_tibble %>% 
            mutate(date = str_extract(df_tibble$pressReleases, "[[:digit:]]{2}.[[:alpha:]]{3} [[:digit:]]{4}")) %>% 
            mutate(ots = str_extract(df_tibble$pressReleases, "OTS[0-9]{4}")) %>% 
            mutate(text = str_extract(df_tibble$pressReleases, "([[:digit:]]{2}.[[:alpha:]]{3} [[:digit:]]{4})((.|\n)*)")) %>% 
            select(-pressReleases)
```

**Finally**, remove "/n" and transform dates to date-format:

```
df_tibble$text <- gsub("\n"," ", df_tibble$text)
df_tibble$date <- dmy(df_tibble$date)
```